# How to reduce build time for Angular 11.1.1?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Initial build time i.e. `ng serve` takes around ~1mins or more.
While compiler is running, Additional changes takes around ~30sec to compile and reflect.

I tried to update to Angular 11.2.5 which has official fix but that's throwing some errors so I could not update.
Is there any other tested workaround to reduce compile time?
pls advise.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, you just need an npx command this method claims to make your angular CLI 10 times Faster.. you should check it out.

```
> npx make-angular-cli-faster
```

Use These links for some details:

https://blog.nrwl.io/discover-how-to-make-the-angular-cli-faster-by-up-to-10-times-more-2d51d59decb9

https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-angular-cli-faster